# Creating a UINT32 from 4 floats

Tags: c++, text, directx

Ok.

I'm working with the FW1FontWrapper code for use with DirectX

: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=fw1

This has removed my need to use an outdated and useless font engine powered by textures.

However, the DrawString function within this Wrapper has a peculiar requirement for a Colour representation.

```
UINT32 Color : In the format 0xAaBbGgRr
```

The data I am given for this task is a constant Alpha value: 1.0f.

And 3 variable float values for R, G and B ranging from 0.0f to 1.0f.

Given the peculiar arrangement of colours within the UNIT32, I'm attempting to write a function that will create this UNIT32 using the 3 float values I am given.

**My Attempt**

```
UINT32 TextClassA::getColour(SentenceType* sentence)
{
    //Convert each float value to its percentage of 255
    int colorb = 255 * sentence->blue;
    int colorg = 255 * sentence->green;
    int colorr = 255 * sentence->red;

    //convert each int to 8 bit Hex
    UINT8 ucolorb = colorb;
    UINT8 ucolorg = colorg;
    UINT8 ucolorr = colorr;

    //Push each hex back onto a UNIT32
    UINT32 color = 0xFF + (ucolorb << 6) + (ucolorg << 4) + (ucolorr << 2);

    return color;
}
```

**SentenceType**

red, green and blue are simply floats for each value of RGB from 0.0-1.0f

**My Idea.**

Was roughly that I could:

1. convert each float value to its percentage of 255 (not too worried about perfect accuracy.
2. Convert those integer values to UINT8s
3. Then push those back onto a UINT32

Comment: This question seems to miss an actual question. Why it doesn't work: `<<6` is a 6 bit shift, when you need a 16 bit shift; `<<4` should be `<<8` and `<<2` shouldn't be shifted at all. You seem to be in a bit over your head, if you're still struggling with the number of bits in a hex digit (4) or where to start counting (0).

Comment: Ahh yes! I also realized this in my solution when I got it to work but the colour values were off! This is my first time messing with bit shifting really so I was basing my logic off my logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation can be made clearer by avoiding all the temporary variables and using something like the code below. That said, any reasonable optimizing compiler should generate the same code in both cases.

```
UINT32 TextClassA::getColour(SentenceType* sentence)
{
    //Convert color components to value between 0 and 255.
    UINT32 r = 255 * sentence->red;
    UINT32 b = 255 * sentence->blue;
    UINT32 g = 255 * sentence->green;

    //Combine the color components in a single value of the form 0xAaBbGgRr
    return 0xFF000000 | r | (b << 16) | (g << 8);
}
```

Comment: Typo: `return color` should be removed.

Comment: @MichaelSurette Thanks.

Comment: Far cleaner!  Thank you for the review!

Answer (score -1):

**I figured it out!!!**

```
UINT32 TextClassA::getColour(SentenceType* sentence)
{
    //Convert each float value to its percentage of 255
    int colorb = 255 * sentence->blue;
    int colorg = 255 * sentence->green;
    int colorr = 255 * sentence->red;

    //convert each int to 8 bit Hex
    UINT8 ucolorb = 0x00 + colorb;
    UINT8 ucolorg = 0x00 + colorg;
    UINT8 ucolorr = 0x00 + colorr;

    //Convert each UINT8 to a UINT32
    UINT32 u32colorb = ucolorb;
    UINT32 u32colorg = ucolorg;
    UINT32 u32colorr = ucolorr;

    //Create final UINT32s and push the converted UINT8s back onto each.
    UINT32 u32finalcolorb = 0x00000000 | (u32colorb << 16);
    UINT32 u32finalcolorg = 0x00000000 | (u32colorg << 8);
    UINT32 u32finalcolorr = 0x00000000 | (u32colorr);

    //0xAaBbGgRr
    //Push each hex back onto a UNIT32
    UINT32 color = 0xFF000000 | u32finalcolorb | u32finalcolorg | 
        u32finalcolorr;

    return color;
}
```

**My Mistake**

...I believe, was trying to push UINT8s back, causing overflows, so I needed to convert to UINT32s first.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: I moved your solution from the question to your answer. Please post it as an answer to begin with next time. Also, if you have a new question (under the solution in the question you were asking if this code could be optimized for speed), ask it as a separate question. (And this future question would fit better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Johan I attempted to do so, however I have to wait two days to set my answer as a solving one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Thanks for the admin work. In regards to your separate point, sometimes I think code is too spread out, and for such a small question as this, people looking for the answer would find it more convenient to see the solution in the same place as the question.

Thank you for suggesting CodeReview though, I'll keep that in mind in the future